# Cannot execute binary file on CentOS amd64

Tags: c#, linux, bash, .net-core, x86-64

**I am trying to run a simple program on CentOS.**

The program:

```
using System;
namespace helloworld
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            returnHello();
         }
         static string returnHello()
         {
            return "hwdy ha";
         }
     }
}
```

**My publish settings are:**

1. **Configuration:** Release|Any CPU
2. **Target framework:** netcoreapp2.1
3. **Deployment mode:** self contained
4. **target runtime:** linux-x64
5. **target location:** bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\

**In a terminal I run**

> dotnet publish --self-contained -r linux-x64 -c release

Then take the folder \publish and copy it over to my CentOS machine.

**using file helloworld, I see the file details:**

> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64,version 1(SYSV), dynamically linked
>   (uses shared libs), for GNU/linux.2.6.32,
>   BuildID[sha1]=0x22d087f79061d441f9f6d007bf336f380c1214db, stripped

using uname -r:

> 3.2.0-3-amd64

In CentOS, I go into the publish folder and run: bash helloworld. In response, I get

> helloworld: cannot execute binary file

.

I am not sure what I am missing here, to me it seems the file is targeting the right OS but I cannot execute the file in CentOS. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try CPU ANY?

Comment: yes, sorry I missed writing that.

Comment: What version of CentOS is this? 6?

Comment: @OmairMajid, when I run "uname -or" I get 3.2.0-3-amd64 GNU/Linux. I am not entirely certain if it is 6 or not.

Comment: Try `cat /etc/*-release`.

Comment: @OmairMajid results: PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux wheezy/sid"                                                                                                                          
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"                                                                                                                                            
ID=debian                                                                                                                                                          
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: You need to switch to a more recent os for .NET Core, like CentOS 7 or Debian 9.

First, based on the `/etc/*release` output, you are using Debian wheezy (aka **[Debian 7](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/)**). A couple of things to note: This was released in 2013 and End-of-Life'd in 2016. In other words, you are using an operating system that's not supported anymore, by anyone. It's not supported by .NET Core. It's not supported by Debian itself. (It's certainly not supported by CentOS)

Second, every release of .NET Core has a list of platforms (and specific versions of platforms) it supports. Older versions of those platforms lack features, compatibility, or something else that makes .NET Core unsuitable for running there.

.NET Core 2.1 [supports these operating systems](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/2.1-supported-os.md). For Debian, it only supports **Debian 9** (and, I assume, later versions as they are released).

Since .NET Core supports Debian 9, it makes use of a number of features in the C library (`glibc`) that require a recent version of `glibc`. Debian 7 doesn't have that recent version of `glibc`, so it can't run .NET Core 2.1 applications.

You should try a more recent version of Debian, CentOS or some other Linux distribution. I know that .NET Core 2.1 works well on RHEL (and CentOS by extension). It should work well on recent versions of Debian and Ubuntu too.

There are a couple of ways to modify .NET Core and to work around this error, but it's rather advanced and would leave you with unable to update to new point releases of .NET Core, so I don't reccommend it: you can bootstrap .NET Core itself (as in, re-compile .NET Core itself) to support Debian 7 and then use that to run your application.

Comment: Hello, I wish that I could update that machine, however unfortunately this suggestion is not possible for me. I do appreciate the recommendation though. The company I work for is concerned that updating that machine will cause other issues with legacy software and refuses to allow this. I found that I could build Go programs successfully for this machine though, so I do have a solution going forward. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Don't run `bash` on a binary executable, just run it directly with `./helloworld`**.

`bash` is a shell-script interpreter and refuses to read non-text files.  e.g.

```
$ bash /bin/ls
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

If `./helloworld` doesn't work, also try `strace ./helloworld` and `ldd ./helloworld` to check for a bad ELF interpreter (dynamic linker) path embedded in the executable.

Comment: Thank you. I tried ./helloworld and got Permission denied, I then tried the "ldd ./helloworld" and got "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ./helloworld)". for the "strace ./helloworld", I got strace: command not found.

Comment: I looked at the above comment, and then ran "chmod +x helloworld", I think I was missing the executable permission. Now when I run ./helloworld, I only get "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ./helloworld) "

Comment: I had made the same hello world program in go (named: helloworldgo) and built it for linux amd64. I wanted see which would build for linux easier. Running the go version with ./helloworldgo ran it just fine. @Peter thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Patrick: yup, "permission denied" is definitely just from missing `+x` permission.  `strace` and `ltrace` can be useful tools for debugging low-level problems like this (to see what actual system calls processes are making, e.g. what paths they're looking at.  `strace -e file ./hello` is often useful).  I'd recommend installing `strace`; all mainstream Linux distros package it.

Comment: Your library version error shows a C++ library ABI version mismatch between the build host and where you're trying to run it.  Unlike `libc`, `libstdc++` does have change in incompatible ways without incrementing the `.so.6` to a different filename, so they do symbol-versioning stuff to give dynamic-linker errors instead of hard-to-debug mysterious crashes.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I cannot change anything on the target machine, so I will be going with golang for this task since it didn't encounter the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Patrick: You might be able to get your build machine to compile+link against the appropriate libstdc++ version, instead of whatever it uses.